# save and find uuid by mysql and yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, find, uuid

key column in table is char(36) utf8_general_ci

//save no problem

```
$key_Ad= Yii::app()->db->createCommand('select UUID()')->queryScalar();
$modelAd->key=$key_Ad;
$modelAd->save()
```

//but problem in find

```
$post=Ad::model()->find( "key = :key",array(':key'=>$key_Ad) );
```

---------------------->Error

CDbException

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = '3f837af1-8a16-11e4-b111-00241d5e096e' LIMIT 1' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `ad` `t` WHERE key = :key LIMIT 1 (C:\xampp\htdocs\framework\db\CDbCommand.php:543)

## 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\framework\db\CDbCommand.php(415): CDbCommand->queryInternal('fetch', Array, Array)#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(1351): CDbCommand->queryRow()#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(1456): CActiveRecord->query(Object(CDbCriteria))#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\agahi\protected\controllers\ImageController.php(34): CActiveRecord->find('key = :key', Array)#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(49): ImageController->actionUploadImage()#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\framework\web\CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\framework\web\CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\framework\web\CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('UploadImage')#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('image/UploadIma...')#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\framework\base\CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\agahi\index.php(13): CApplication->run()#12 {main}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have used the reserved mySql keyword 'key' as your column name. That's what generates the syntax error. It is best that you rename your column to something different than 'key', e.g. 'key1' or 'key_ad'.

In mySql you can still execute the query with the column named 'key' by escaping it in the select statement using '`', I'm not sure if you can do this in Yii, you should try it.

But the best solution is to just rename the column and not use reserved words as column names in the future.